# How to wait for event request of Rudderstack JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, pipeline, rudderstack-sdk

I want to redirect the user after the track event or any other event fired by rudderstack has be done.

As I've tested on *track* event it doesn't not return a promise.

How can I wait for the requests to end to redirect after?

Below there is an example of what i am doing:

```
// import    
import { track, load, ready, identify } from 'rudder-sdk-js';
[...]

await load(write_key, data_plane_url)

await ready(async () => {
  await identify(hashedId, userInfo);

  await track('ORDER_APPROVED');    
});

history.push('/some-page')
```

I'm using it with React btw.